# How to mockery mock internal method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

#### Target.php

```
<?php

class Target
{
    public function validate()
    {
        $this->getData();
        return true;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

#### TargetTest.php

```
<?php

class TargetTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testValidate()
    {
        $mock = m::mock('Target');
        $mock->shouldReceive('getData')
            ->once();
        $expected = $this->exp->validate();

        $this->assertTrue($expected);
    }
}
```

#### result

`Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method getData() from Mockery_1_ExpWarning should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

I use `Mockery` as mock tool, the example always about how to mock with `DI`, I would like to know can I mock internal method?

Comment: your TargetTest class is little bit confused. Is the ExpWarning the real class name of Target class? Who his $this->exp object? why not $mock? please explain better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Partial Mocks features](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html) of the testing framework for mock only the `getData` method and describe an expectation.

As (working) Example:

```
use Mockery as m;

class TargetTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testValidate()
    {
        $mock = m::mock('Target[getData]');
        $mock->shouldReceive('getData')
            ->once();
        $expected = $mock->validate();

        $this->assertTrue($expected);
    }
}
```

Hope this help